# How to decrypt a value which contains special ColdFusion characters?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am using ColdFusion to encrypt and decrypt. I have variable active with a value 1. I want to create a URL containing the encrypted value of active like:

```
http://localhost:8500/blueline/ActivateRegistration.cfm?email=abc@gmail.com&active=!#
```

Here `!#` is the encrypted value of 1.

At the other end ie ActivateRegistration.cfm I need to decrypt `active` with same private key and find the original value. But I am not getting correct encrypted string when I try the following code:

```
<cfset activeValue = url.active>
```

The reason is the encrypted value also contains the special character `#` within the string. Can anyone help? Also how can I handle ColdFusion special characters/keywords?

Comment: Which algorithm and encoding are you using? Without knowing more I would suggest returning the encrypted value in base64. Also, be sure to [url encode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c2f.html) the url parameters. If that does not help, can you post an example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other guys have covered how to escape URL-meaningful characters that occur within a URL value, but there's one last piece of the puzzle that stands clarification / correction.

You're not having problems with the encrypted string because # is a special character *to ColdFusion*, it's because it has special meaning in the URL itself.  Within a URL, a # is the delimiter between the address of the document on the server, and the specific fragment being targeted within the document (ie: a bookmark / anchor tag).  As this information is deemed not relevant to the server, the browser never sends it, so the server never gets it.

It's similar to if you had a parameter value which in itself had an embedded ampersand (&): as far as URLs go, that's a delimiter between parameters, not part of the parameter value, so CF would not see that as part of the value of a URL variable, it'd see it as the delimiter between two variables.

To avoid all this confusion, as the other respondents said, you need to always URL-encode values that need to go on a URL that contain characters that are [meaningful to the URL-addressing schema itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

Comment: Duh, I was so caught up in url encoding I did not bother to explain why. Good explanation. That is the right answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfparam name="url.active" default="">
<cfoutput>
    <a href="#cgi.script_name#?active=#urlEncodedFormat('!##')#">This String Contains CFML Values</a>
    #urlDecode(url.active)#
</cfoutput>
```

There's a couple things you need to do.

1. You need to replace any `#` characters with `##` to escape them for ColdFusion.
2. If you are transporting weird characters in the URL, its safest to transport them with urlEncodedFormat() and decode them with urlDecode() or base64 should be good too.

As Leigh mentioned, I'd like to see how you're generating this encrypted text to better help you.

Comment: I think we need more information. Because they should not have to escape pound signs within the dynamic results of `encrypt`. Only if they are hard coded into the .cfm page. Also, `URL` variables are automatically decoded. So you can skip the `urlDecode`.